# Wordpress Admin Thickbox: Remove Margins/Padding

Tags: admin, css, javascript, thickbox

I've added a Thickbox to an admin page by adding the the following action hook to add the library code

```
add_action( 'in_admin_footer', function(){   
    add_thickbox();    
});
```

And then triggering an inline thick box manually via some javascript code

```
tb_show(null,'#TB_inline?height=300&width=300&inlineId=id_of_div_with_my_thickbox',false);
```

When I do this, the thickbox has some margins/padding on the left and right (see in screenshot below how everything is centered)

[image]

I'd like to

1. Remove these styles for everything is flush against the Thickbox (as a style reset)
2. But **only** for my Thickbox.

Re: #2 -- This is something for a plugin that's going to be on many admin backend pages.  I know I can target the `id=TB_ajaxContent` div to change the style -- but this runs the risk of breaking other Thickboxes added to the system

Is there known science for this in the Wordpress community?  Or am I on my own as a plugin developer to create this functionality myself?

Comment: If the goal of this is to have a button that shows a modal with an autocomplete box, then why not improve your UX by just placing the autocomplete box inside the original UI rather than requiring a modal thickbox creating UX friction?

Comment: @TomJNowell That's good UX advice, but that's not the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for a custom stylesheet. Copy and paste all the CSS from the original `thickbox.css` in your custom stylesheet.

Now you can edit your custom CSS and add the code below in your plugin.

```
function get_thickbox() {
    // Add the original thickbox
    add_thickbox();

    // register your custom stylesheet
    // Make sure its in your speciefied folder!
    wp_register_style( 'thickbox_css', plugins_url( 'pluginname/stylesheet.css' ) );

    // enqueue our new stylesheet
    enqueue_style( 'thickbox_css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_thickbox');

// Thats it!
// You can now reach your customized thickbox by:
get_thickbox();
```